# Database per tenant with Fluent NHibernate & StructureMap

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, structuremap, multi-tenant

I'm currently using StructureMap to inject an `NHibernateRegistry` instance into my DAL, which configures NHibernate for a single connection string and bootstraps a Singleton `FluentConfiguration` for my single-user app.

How should I modify my Fluent NHibernate configuration to use a different database based on a `{tenant}` routing parameter in my routing URL?

### Routing example:

```
{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

...where requests for `branch1/Home/Index` and `branch2/Home/Index` use the same application code, but different databases to retrieve the data displayed.

I solved this problem in the past for StructureMap and LINQ by injecting a per-request `TenantContext` object, which retrieved the routing parameter from the `HttpContext` it accepted as a constructor parameter and specified a different LINQ data context.

However, I suspect NHibernate has a better of handling this than I could cook up.

### Partial `NHibernateRegistry` class

```
public class NHibernateRegistry : Registry
{
    // ... private vars here

    public NHibernateRegistry()
    {
        var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
                .MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => 
                    c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("TenantConnectionStringKey")))
                    // where to inject this key?
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .Mappings(x => 
                x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(typeof(UserMap).Assembly)

        For<FluentConfiguration>().Singleton().Use(cfg);

        var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

        For<ISessionFactory>().Singleton()
            .Use(sessionFactory);
        For<ISession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use(x => x.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
        For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use<UnitOfWork>();
        For<IDatabaseBuilder>().Use<DatabaseBuilder>();

    }
}
```

### StructureMap configuration:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void ConfigureStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(Init);
    }

    private static void Init(IInitializationExpression x)
    {
        x.AddRegistry(new NHibernateRegistry()); // from Data project
    }
}
```

I'm new to NHibernate, so I am unsure of scoping my sessions and configurations. Does NHibernate have a built-in way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in an a module

```
return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("IMB"))
            .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().QueryCacheFactory<StandardQueryCacheFactory>()
                         .RegionPrefix("IMB")
                         .ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>()
                         .UseMinimalPuts()).UseReflectionOptimizer())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("IMB.Data")))
           .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("IMB.Security")))

           .ExposeConfiguration(
            c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => _configuration = cfg)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a whirl. Are all the `.RegionPrefix("IMB")` (presumably the tenant id) stuff native to NHibernate?

Comment: No the .RegionPrefix is the cache prefix fn uses to handle the cached entities

Comment: on closer inspection, this does not affect the connection string based on any tenant IDs. How is this a multi-tenant solution?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question.
You can try this.
[link](http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2009/03/30/using-nhibernate-with-multiple-databases/)
Where are you calling your bootrapper from? global.asax?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you really want your `ISessionFactory` object to be a singleton. This means its best *not* to specify the connection string when creating the `ISessionFactory`. Have your tried creating the `ISessionFactory` without specifying a connection string and then passing a manually created connection to `ISessionFactory.OpenSession`?

For example:

```
public ISession CreateSession()
{
    string tennantId = GetTennantId();
    string connStr = ConnectionStringFromTennant(tennantId);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();
    session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(conn);
}
```

And then tell StructureMap to call this method.

The downside is that you can't now from build the database schema when creating the `ISessionFactory`, but maybe creating database schemas in web applications isn't that great an idea anyway?